# Gazebo initial view of world - my rendering:gui fltk tag is not working

Tags: simulator-gazebo, gazebo-simulator, camera, ros-fuerte, world

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 12.04
Fuerte
Gazebo 1.0.2

Hi
The following posts describe how to set the initial distance/orientation of the static camera view when your Gazebo .world file loads:
http://answers.ros.org/question/11178/initial-view-after-gazebo-starts/   
http://answers.ros.org/question/12658/how-to-change-gazebo-gui-focal-lengthfov/

using a block in your .world file like this:

```
   <rendering:gui>
    <type>fltk</type>
    <size>480 320</size>
    <pos>0 0</pos>
    <frames>
      <row height="100%">
        <camera width="100%">
          <xyz>0.3 0 3</xyz>
          <rpy>0 90 90</rpy>
        </camera>
      </row>
    </frames>
  </rendering:gui>
```

but it seems like this code is being ignored by my Gazebo.  
No matter what parameters I change, Gazebo always loads with the robot model at the same distance and orientation. Its annoying having to zoom-in, unlike Rviz.

Is anyone able to change their default Gazebo camera view?  @marcus-bader is this still working for you?

cheers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39862/gazebo-initial-view-of-world---my-rendering:gui-fltk-tag-is-not-working/) by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1103 on 2012-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using electric, Ubuntu 11.10, and above code works w/o a glitch. It might be possible that while launching gazebo it is reading these parameters from somewhere else as well. I guess gazebo takes the first value, in case there are multiple tags.

Kindly post your entire .world file and also how u r launching it.

Just curious, any idea what does fltk stands for, in type tag?

---

Originally posted by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) with karma: 339 on 2012-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0